# Concatinate mkv from segmented recordings of rtsp

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, mp4, matroska

I recorded an rtsp stream to a series of segmented files via the following

```
ffmpeg -t $((5*60*60)) \
    -i 'rtsp://....@10.0.0.132:88/videoMain' \
    -c copy -map 0 \
    -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_format mkv \
    "recording-%03d.mkv" \
    2> "${dir}log"
```

When playing these individual recordings back in VLC, I notice that the timestamps in each file increase continuously, so the first second of the last file is not timestamp 00:00 of that file, but rather 4:59:00. Since each clip is only 60 seconds long, it makes it very hard to skip to a position the video with the mouse, because the whole 1 minute clip is just a small fraction of the multi-hour track bar.

Since the total size of all the small recordings is only 1.5 GiB, I figured maybe it'd be easier to just concatenate them to undo the segmentation. My first attempt also moved the video to a MP4 container so that Chromium could play them.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(find . -name '*.mkv' -printf "file '$PWD/%p'\n"|sort) -c:v copy output.mp4
```

There were a few problems with this. First, it started at the wrong place. The contents of recording-000.mkv don't match the first 60 seconds of video played. After the first minute of video played, the video stops updating. VLC continues to advance the track bar and the timestamp goes up, but the video feed never updates. A few decoding errors are logged if I try skipping to arbitrary points in the video. VLC seems to think it's 749 hours long.

So in my second attempt I left it as an mkv and I tried adding `segment_time_metadata`, figuring that maybe it'd help with preserving the timestamps. Well I never found out if it did or not because after ~1TiB of writing to the output file I killed it.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -segment_time_metadata 1 -i <(find . -name '*.mkv' -printf "file '$PWD/%p'\n"|sort) -c:v copy output.mkv
```

I suspect the RTSP stream, which is from an IP camera, is probably not well formed. However ff I just record it to a single mp4 file, then VLC plays it fine and the timestamps are all correct. So the issue seems to be a combination of the malformed stream and segmentation+concat.

```
ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://......@10.0.0.132:88/videoMain':
  Metadata:
    title           : IP Camera Video
    comment         : videoMain
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1280x720, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_mulaw (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[aac @ 0x5641eaec06c0] Too many bits 8832.000000 > 6144 per frame requested, clamping to max
Output #0, mp4, to 'live.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : IP Camera Video
    comment         : videoMain
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1280x720, q=2-31, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac
[mp4 @ 0x5641eaec1580] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
```

Comment: "-f concat" suitable for raw formats: "-segment_format mpegts", *.ts files can be concatenated

Comment: In the future, I'll stop using mkv. But for the files I've already recorded, what should I do to concatenate them?

Comment: copy all of them to .ts: "ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy output.ts" and concat. Copy to ts will clear header of mkv, which prevents the files being joined normally.